# Need help for a specific SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help.
I have to do a very specific SQL Statement and I just can't figure out, how it should work.

What I got is two tables:

```
TABLE1: shop_articles CONTAINS pos (int), manufacturer (varchar)
TABLE2: shop_texts CONTAINS pos (int), text (text)
```

So I got two Variables `$keyManufacturer` and `$keyText`

What I want is a intersection where `$keyManufacturer` matches 'manufacturer' and check, if on the same 'pos' 'text' matches `$keyText`

I'm pretty sure, that's not too hard, but I can't figure out the solution.
Any help?

Comment: `pos` column in table `shop_texts` is a foreign key of `shop_articles` table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `pos` FROM  `shop_artciles` a, `shop_texts` b WHERE `a.manufacturer` = 
             '$keyManufacturer'  AND `b.text` = '$ketText' AND `a.pos` = `b.pos`
```

Here there are 3 conditions in the `WHERE` clause and the result is the rows that match all three conditions. Think this is what you want. You can try `joins` in you are interested.

```
SELECT `a.pos` FROM `shop_artciles` AS a LEFT JOIN `shop_texts` AS b ON 
             `a.pos`= `b.pos` WHERE`a.manufacturer` = '$keyManufacturer'  
                                         AND `b.text` = '$ketText'
```